# Spring Batch JobExecutionException - ConcurrencyFailureException

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch, hsqldb

I am unable to reproduce this error in my DEV environment, but it is happening randomly in our staging and QA environments. It has not happened in PROD yet, but that is probably just luck of the draw. Since I can not reproduce the error, I am at a loss for how to troubleshoot it. My best guess from reading the error dumps is that the Spring Job Transaction table is not properly handling the multithreaded nature of the app.

The code takes data from many sources, does some transforms, then creates data files to send to other sources. There is no need to save state between runs, on error we run a cleanup script, and start the process fresh. It is a single "job" but has many steps, and the steps use FlowBuilder to run steps in parallel.

A rerun of the process always clears it. Yesterday I ran the process over and over in my DEV environment and could not get it to happen a single time.

Here is the bean in question:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {    
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)     
        .build();
    return db;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
2017-06-13 07:16:18.543 ERROR 403 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           : Encountered fatal error executing job

org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:215) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:232) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:124) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:118) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:366) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.dcsg.batch.Main.main(Main.java:146) [UniversalFeedGenerator.jar!/:VERSION 1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [UniversalFeedGenerator.jar!/:VERSION 1.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=caliaFlow at state=caliaFlow.Calia Writer with exception
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:178) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, STEP_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]; transaction rollback: serialization failure; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:233) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.saveExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:187) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.add(SimpleJobRepository.java:171) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687769/how-can-i-resolve-this-sqltransactionrollbackexception-with-hsqldb-in-spring-bat)

Comment: Use these parameters when using your configuration: `hsqldb.tx=mvcc`.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the answer suggested by Haythem, but it may be a while before I can tell if it works. It is so random in occurrence and unreproducible I will just have to request a build to QA/Stage and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the data source to this

```
  @Bean
  public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.enforce_strict_size=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
  }
```

Fixed it. The key change is using "tx=mvcc" which the Embedded Datasource does not support. That enables "Multiversion concurrency control"

This question explains what MVCC is and why to use it in the answers:

[Database: What is Multiversion Concurrency Control (MVCC) and who supports it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499/database-what-is-multiversion-concurrency-control-mvcc-and-who-supports-it)